# Difference between isnan and comparison to self

Tags: glsl

In GLSL, what is the difference between `isnan(x)` and `!(x == x)`?

Comment: You mean, besides the fact that one of these is self-explanatory and the other appears to be gibberish?

Comment: @NicolBolas comparison with self is the usual way to test for nan with standard conforming floats and glsl is, as far as I know, required to abide by them. Therefore I consider adding another function as superfluous (and confusing), unless (or especially if) it has a different behavior.

Comment: "Usual" is in the eye of the beholder. C99 has `isnan`; C++11 has `std::isnan`. Java has `Java.lang.Double.isNan`. C# has `Double.IsNan`. IEEE-754 even has a specific predicate called `isNaN`. It seems to me that those relying on `!(x==x)` are due to using standard libraries that are deficient, not because it is "usual". An explicit function is always easier to understand than an idiom that must be learned.

Comment: I did not know that such functions were so common. Thanks for mentioning them.
Can I conclude that the behavior is indeed the same?

By one's personal experience, is it possible that the two methods behave differently on some devices?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

IEEE-754 defines the `isNaN` property, which determines if a value is NaN. However, it is also defined to be a non-signaling operation; calling `isNaN` on an sNaN will never result in a signaled failure. By contrast, equality testing may signal when given sNaN values.

Now, GLSL explicitly states that signaling doesn't matter:

> Support for signaling NaNs is not required and exceptions are never raised.

But of course, there's also the fact that `isnan` is a vector function, while `!(x == x)` only works on scalars. So if you want to test if any of the elements of a `vec3` are NaN, you can do `any(isnan(some_vec))`, while the equality-testing equivalent would be even more obtuse and verbose: `any(not(equal(some_vec, some_vec)))`.

And all of that ignores the simple usability reasons for having `isnan`. `!(x == x)` is an idiom which must be learned, while `isnan` is an easily looked up function whose name tells you want it does. After all, most users of floats tend to forget about NaN, so such an expression seems like a tautology, while "isnan" explicitly reminds such people that NaNs are a real thing and they are reading code where that fact is important.

Also, as previously stated, `isNaN` is a property defined by IEEE-754. It is also a function provided by the standard libraries of C99, C++11, Java, C#, Swift, Go, JavaScript, and I can keep going, but I think my point is clear.

Comment: Great!
So other languages actually have a difference between the two approaches.
And glsl has the function just to mimic those languages, even if there is no difference (apart from the readability point).
Thanks for the explanation :D